# Upgrade Centos 6.10 to 6.9

Tags: centos6, centos-6.9

I am trying to update my Centos VPS.
I have one on Centos 6.9 but an another one in Centos 6.10

And i can not upgrade it.
I tried folowing commands :

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

# yum update
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror, presto, priorities
Configuration du processus de mise à jour
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.ehv.weppel.nl
 * rpmforge: miroir.univ-paris13.fr
Aucun paquet marqué pour mise à jour -> No packet to install.
```

So i tried the following commands :

```
# yum clean all
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror, presto, priorities
Nettoyage des dépôts : atomic base epel extras rpmforge updates
Nettoyage complet
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
0 delta-package files removed, by presto

# yum update
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror, presto, priorities
Configuration du processus de mise à jour
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                                         |  21 kB     00:00
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * rpmforge: miroir.univ-paris13.fr
atomic                                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB     00:00
atomic/primary_db                                                                                                                     | 620 kB     00:00
base                                                                                                                                  | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                                                       | 4.7 MB     00:00
epel                                                                                                                                  | 3.2 kB     00:00
epel/primary                                                                                                                          | 3.2 MB     00:00
epel                                                                                                                                             12522/12522
extras                                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                     |  25 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                                                                                              | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge/primary_db                                                                                                                   | 2.7 MB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                               | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                    | 645 kB     00:00
Aucun paquet marqué pour mise à jour -> No packet to install.
```

I tried also :

```
# yum install kernel
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror, presto, priorities
Configuration du processus d'installation
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * rpmforge: miroir.univ-paris13.fr
Le paquet kernel-2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64 est déjà installé dans sa dernière version (Already installed in last version)
Rien à faire (nothing to do)
```

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry i think i am stupid !!

I was in centos 6.9 and after yum update it is centos 6.10
So i think centos 6.10 is more uptodate as 6.9.

But maybe i am wrong ?

Comment: The current release is `centos-release-6-10.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`

Comment: @Ouimaisnon Toiy when you "yum update", the OS updates it to the latest version of that release. For example, in your case, its already centOs 6.10 and the last version for CentOs 6 is 6.10 so it wont update any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CentOS release 6.10 (Final) is the final and last updated CentOS 6

The CentOS release 6.9 is older version than 6.10 so don't be confused its not 6.1..

See this link: https://blog.centos.org/2018/07/release-for-centos-linux-6-10-i386-and-x86_64/